# Node.JS Module with custom parameter and EventEmitter not working

Tags: node.js, node-modules, require, eventemitter

Hello i am trying to create a Node.JS based module which will accept a parameter when required will be called and also it will be able to raise events that caller module will be able to listen on my approach is some thing like below

```
let events = require('events');

exports.Inititalize = function (parameter) 
{
    let emitter = events.EventEmitter();

    //some initialization code here
    //at some point need to raise event e.g.
    //emitter.emit('status', 'Hi there i am an event, you provided ' + parameter)

    return emitter;
}
```

and the caller script invokes it as below

```
let myModule = require('./mymodule.js').Inititalize('my parameter');

myModule.on('status', function (status) { //TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined but as far as i know "on" is the part of EvenEmitter that i returned
    console.log(status);
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just forgot the `new` keyword:

```js
let emitter = new events.EventEmitter();
```

Comment: did not tried this fix but i solved the issue by inheriting the events in my class and wrote all code in class constructor